# Generate values in a column in a Dataframe, based on a condition and copy paste values down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create two new columns (AA & BB) in my dataset that get filled based on a condition (is = 1) of the values in A or B as well as a condition in C. AA only looks at A and C and BB only looks at B and C. If a condition is met then the value 1 is printed in column AA or BB until it gets interrupted by a condition in C.

In the below example in column A, index 1 the condition is met and it prints a 1 in column AA until index 4 where a 1 can be found in column C which negates the previous condition and it resumes printing 0. The same for column B at index 6 that gets interrupted at index 9 by the condition in column C.

```
index   A   B   C   AA  BB
0       0   0   0   0   0
1       1   0   0   1   0
2       0   0   0   1   0
3       0   0   0   1   0
4       0   0   1   0   0
5       0   0   0   0   0
6       0   1   0   0   1
7       0   0   0   0   1
8       0   0   0   0   1
9       0   0   1   0   0
```

I tried the below solution which I found online but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for i, b in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
        if b[1]['A'] == 1.0:
            AA = 1            
        elif b[1]['B'] == 1.0:
            BB = 1
        elif b[1]['C'] == 1.0:
            AA = 0
            BB = 0
        df.loc[i]['AA'] = AA
        df.loc[i]['BB'] = BB
```

Comment: what happen if A has 2nd `1` after C `1`? I.e. what is the value of `AA` if `A` at index `7` is `1`?

Comment: Instead of ELIF statements use IF statements. If the first condition is met, it will move to the next row, and thus not resolve your third elif statement

Comment: @AndyL. if A has a 2nd 1 then it would need to repeat the process, e.g. put a 1 into column AA and start copy pasting it down until it breaks by meeting the C condition.

Comment: @BramvanHoutI tried it with the if statements but unfortunately get the same results. The code works (e.g.) no errors, but there are also no values in AA or BB

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    AA = 0
    BB = 0
    # first row only dependent on A/B
    if index == 0:
        if row['A'] == 1:
            AA = 1
        if row['B'] == 1:
            BB = 1
    else:  # all other rows dependent on previous value too
        if row['A'] == 1 or df.loc[i-1, 'AA'] == 1:
            AA = 1
        if row['B'] == 1 or df.loc[i-1, 'BB'] == 1:
            BB = 1
        if row['C'] == 1: # if C is 1, override AA/BB to zero
           AA = 0
           BB = 0
    df.loc[i, 'AA'] = AA
    df.loc[i, 'BB'] = BB
```

edited: caught typo where value of C was not correctly setting AA and BB to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this. Use `idxmax` to find the index where first `1` appears in `A` and `B`. Use them to slice `A`-`C` and `B`-`C`. Next, `cumsum` and clip negative values to `0` and assign to `AA`, `BB`. Finally, `fillna` and cast to `int`

```
i_a = df.A.idxmax()
i_b = df.B.idxmax()
df['AA'] = (df.A - df.C).loc[i_a:].cumsum().clip(lower=0)
df['BB'] = (df.B - df.C).loc[i_b:].cumsum().clip(lower=0)
df.loc[:, ['AA', 'BB']] = df.loc[:, ['AA', 'BB']].fillna(0).astype(int)

Out[1844]:
   index  A  B  C  AA  BB
0  0      0  0  0  0   0
1  1      1  0  0  1   0
2  2      0  0  0  1   0
3  3      0  0  0  1   0
4  4      0  0  1  0   0
5  5      0  0  0  0   0
6  6      0  1  0  0   1
7  7      0  0  0  0   1
8  8      0  0  0  0   1
9  9      0  0  1  0   0
```